# Drop down style not displaying properly in Mac?

Tags: javascript, html, css, macos-sierra

I created a drop down box for a website and it is not displayed properly in Mac.

Snippet:

```css
select {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  /* remove the strong OSX influence from Webkit */
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Sushi</option>
  <option>Blue cheese with crackers</option>
  <option>Steak</option>
  <option>Other</option>
</select>
```

It is correctly displayed in others. The problem is with Mac only.

Comment: What is it actually meant to look like, rather than "is not displayed properly in Mac"

Answer (score 0):

-webkit-appearance:none makes the item display wrong but not everywhere, try it like this:

```
select {
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 0;
}
```